# Use sed to print lines in a file if the first 10 character contains a specific string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the following file on my Ubuntu machine:

file.txt

```
http://example.com/https:/www.google.com
http://test.example.com
https://www.example.com
https://www.click.example.com
http://example.com
http://test.example.com
https://www.example.com/https:/www.google.com
https://www.click.example.com
```

I want the output in the new file:

new_file.txt

```
https://www.example.com
https://www.click.example.com
https://www.example.com/https:/www.google.com
https://www.click.example.com
```

I am using sed as shown below, but it includes in the output file all lines that contain **https** anywhere in the line.

```
sed -n '/https/p' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

I want to limit the search to the first 5 characters: if it finds the `https` in the first 5, then print the line and otherwise skip it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` uses basic regex (`BRE`) as default to search for text, so you can use [its syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-syntax.html):

> ^
>
> Matches the null string at beginning of the pattern space, i.e. what appears after the circumflex must appear at the beginning of the pattern space.

So, for you:

```
sed -n '/^https/p' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

Or use `grep`:

```
grep '^https' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

Comment: That is called regular expression (regex), a text matching syntax. You should dig into it, it's great stuff.

Comment: There is no magic... Just like `h` matches an `h` in a line, `^` matches the beginning of a line.